# Clojure documentation in Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime

Is it possible to view Clojure function documentation in Emacs? Namely, can I configure Emacs to lookup Clojure functions under the cursor?

I'm using clojure-mode and SLIME. Oddly, I can't even use `apropos` or `dir` in SLIME's repl, although they're automatically loaded by `lein repl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the function `slime-describe-symbol`, which is usually bound to <kbd>C-c C-d d</kbd>.

Place the point somewhere near the function name and hit <kbd>C-c</kbd>, then <kbd>C-d</kbd>, and then <kbd>d</kbd>.

There's also `slime-describe-function`, bound to <kbd>C-c C-d f</kbd>, but I rarely use it, as it's less general than the aforementioned symbol-related lookup function.

To see all the documentation-related functions, press <kbd>C-c C-d C-h</kbd>. These bindings are not specific to Clojure; they are instead defined by SLIME, and will work as well if not better for other Lisp dialects.

Comment: <kbd>C-c C-d C-d</kbd> is an alias for <kbd>C-c C-d d</kbd> and is easier to hit as you don't have to release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key at the right moment.

Comment: True. By now, I have the muscle memory built up to use the other sequence naturally. I think it comes from associating `C-c C-d` with the documentation dispatch prefix, stopping at that point to think of which documentation I want, and then preceding with the final character. Hence, letting go of the Control key corresponds to pausing to decide.

Answer (score 3):

I find the combination of `slime-apropos` and `eldoc` minor mode (make sure you have swank-clojure 1.4.0 as it fixes both of those) better than the `slime-describe-symbol/function` commands mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

From SLIME REPL you can run (use 'clojure.repl).  This will make functions like apropos and doc available